# if( $_GET) if else problem

Tags: php

need help...

the getting input form:

```
<select name="age">     
<option value="25-30">25-30</option>
<option value="31-40">31-40</option>        
<option value="41-50">41-50</option>
<option value="51-60">51-60</option>
</select>
```

example url

```
search/?age=25-30
```

the function php:

```
if ( $_GET['age'] !="25-30") $age = '("A")'; 
elseif ( $_GET['age'] !="31-40") $age = '("B")'; 
elseif ( $_GET['age'] !="41-50") $age = '("C")'; 
elseif ( $_GET['age'] !="51-60") $age = '("D")'; 
else ( $_GET['age'] !="25-30") $age = '("A")'; 

$search ="http://domain.com/?q='.$age;
```

the problem: the $age inside $search always returns A (or 25-30) even though i have selected other values (31-40, 41-50, 51-60)

please help..thanks

Comment: Are you sending the form info back in GET or POST?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`else` should represent a default value and `( $_GET['age'] !="25-30")` should be removed from it and here is what you should have actually:

```
if ( $_GET['age'] =="25-30") $age = '("A")'; 
elseif ( $_GET['age'] =="31-40") $age = '("B")'; 
elseif ( $_GET['age'] =="41-50") $age = '("C")'; 
elseif ( $_GET['age'] =="51-60") $age = '("D")'; 
else $age = '("A")'; // modify accordingly
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do this cleaner using a `switch` statement or an array with values, but before going into examples: Wouldn't it be easier to just set the value to `A`, `B`, `C`... in the `select` in the first place?

Re @Col.Shrapnels comment. Which one looks better. The `if` soup above, or this?

```
switch($_GET["age"])
 {
   case "25-30": $age = "A"; break;
   case "31-40": $age = "B"; break;
   case "41-50": $age = "C"; break;
   case "51-60": $age = "D"; break;
   default:      $age = "E"; break;  // or whatever

 }
```

Comment: Oh no. Why switch? I think it's most useless operator. For the few comparisons `if` is much more readable and arrays for the rest.

Comment: @Col Why not? Switch makes the code much, much better readable IMO. See my update. Don't you think? Are there any actual downsides to using it? Anyway, anything beyond 10 elements should go into an array.

Comment: In my opinion. `if` notation is much nearer to the natural language. Though it doesn't really matter and only matter of taste. Anyway. I'd go for array if number of choices more than 2.

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean

`==`

not

`!=`

Answer (score 2):

How do you think, what does `!=` operator mean?

Anyway,

```
<select name="age">     
<option value="A">25-30</option>
<option value="B">31-40</option>        
<option value="C">41-50</option>
</select>
```

Comment: i did not realize the != :p
the select value would be different if i use the above

Comment: @web yeah, that's intention of this code. if you search for your own site, the code would be even smaller.

Comment: @webdev: You want value `A` for `25-30`, `B` for `31-40`, etc, why not just define that value in the `<option>` directly? That's the whole point of this answer. This way you can just do `$age = $_GET['age'];` without hassling with cumbersome `if-else` blocks.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the "**Not Equal To**" ("**!=**") Operator, and so, unless you select **25-30** from the list (which should result in *(B)*, it will always stop at the first line.

For the full code, I would use:

```
switch( $_GET['age'] ) {
  case '25-30' :
    $age = '("A")'; break;
  case '31-40' :
    $age = '("B")'; break;
  case '41-50' :
    $age = '("C")'; break;
  case '51-60' :
    $age = '("D")'; break;
  default :
    $age = '("A")';
}
```

Comment: hm..i am not sure if i should use switch

Comment: It is an option, whether it is the best or not, of course, depends on the circumstance.